# Using protocol buffer in Windows

Tags: python, windows, protocol-buffers

I am trying to use google protocol buffer in windows with python binding, however I meet some problem during the install step.

Follow the instruction, I have to compile the PB myself using vs, but I have no vs installed on my machine, then I found a window binary at the [download](https://code.google.com/p/protobuf/downloads/detail?name=protoc-2.5.0-win32.zip&can=2&q=) page.

Also I download the full [source code package](https://code.google.com/p/protobuf/downloads/detail?name=protobuf-2.5.0.zip&can=2&q=), then I put the `protoc-2.5.0-win32.zip\protoc.exe` to `C:\windows\system32`.

Then I go to the `protobuf-2.5.0.zip\python` and run the `python setup.py install` to install the python binding.

However I get the error like this:
[image]

And when I check the directory, the file `google\protobuf\compiler` does not exist.

What's the problem?

Is it possible to use it without compiling?

Comment: did you find the answer to this?

Comment: Not yet. Finally I use ubuntu instead. :).

Answer (score 2):

I was just suffering from the same problem.  The solution is to explicitly do the build step before.

```
python setup.py build
python setup.py install
```

That worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Before this package can be installed on windows you need to download the compiler (protoc.exe) and put it in the environment execution path.

After this step is done you can run:

**python setup.py build**

python setup.py install

~yy

Comment: If you built it from source. You can temporarily copy protoc.exe from the build dir (e.g. vsprojects\x64\Release) into the src dir.

Answer (score 0):

```
C:\Users\dev3\protobufcode\protobuf-master\python
$ python setup.py build
$ python setup.py install

C:\Users\dev3\protobufcode
$ python --version
Python 3.6.5
$ python -i build\gen\addressbook_pb2.py
>>> import addressbook_pb2
>>> Person = addressbook_pb2.Person()
>>> person = addressbook_pb2.Person()
>>> person.id = 1234
>>> person.name = "Go Fish"
>>> person.email = "gofish@example.com"
>>> phone = person.phones.add()
>>> phone.number = "111-2222"
>>> phone.type = addressbook_pb2.Person.HOME
>>> person
name: "Go Fish"
id: 1234
email: "gofish@example.com"
phones {
  number: "111-2222"
  type: HOME
}

>>>
```